How to solve maximum transfer question?
I am a student studying electrical engineering. While solving the maximum transfer problem, there was something I didn't know, so I posted a question. I would really appreciate your help.

Two Thevenin solutions (add test current source, Rth calculation through Voc-Isc) were used to solve the following problems
The answers from the two solutions are different, so I wonder where they went wrong.


I decided that it would be okay to solve a branch connected in parallel with a branch without any elements as shown in the problem solving method below, and applied it to the Thevenin problem in the first picture, but I think I was wrong in that part.
Thank you for reading it.


It looks to me as though the dependent source must be 880 V. Not sure there is a finite maximum power into R, as a result of that fact. It's directly applied to R. (Vo = (100 V * 22k*40k + 3*Vo * 10k*40k)/(10k*22k + 10k*40k + 22k*40k) solves as Vo = 880/3.)

Well, the circuit we want to analyze is given by:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
When we use and apply KCL, we can write the following set of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3\\
\\
\text{I}_0+\text{I}_3&=\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5\\
\\
\text{I}_4+\text{I}_5&=\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\text{I}_2+\text{I}_8&=\text{I}_1
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag1
$$
When we use and apply Ohm's law, we can write the following set of equations:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-\text{n}\cdot\text{V}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_4&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}\\
\\
\text{I}_5&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag2
$$
Substituting \$\displaystyle(2)\$ into \$\displaystyle(1)\$, gives:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-\text{n}\cdot\text{V}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_0+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-\text{n}\cdot\text{V}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}&=\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_4}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{n}\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}&=\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_8&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_\text{i}-\text{V}}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag3
$$
Filling in what we know, gives:
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\frac{\displaystyle100-\text{V}}{\displaystyle10\cdot1000}&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle40\cdot1000}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-3\cdot\text{V}}{\displaystyle22\cdot1000}\\
\\
\text{I}_0+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-3\cdot\text{V}}{\displaystyle22\cdot1000}&=\text{I}_6\\
\\
\text{I}_6&=\frac{\displaystyle3\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle30\cdot1000}+\frac{\displaystyle3\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle3\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle30\cdot1000}+\frac{\displaystyle3\cdot\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_5}&=\text{I}_7\\
\\
\text{I}_7&=\text{I}_0+\text{I}_8\\
\\
\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle40\cdot1000}+\text{I}_8&=\frac{\displaystyle100-\text{V}}{\displaystyle10\cdot1000}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$
Solving for \$\displaystyle\text{V}\$, gives:
$$\frac{\displaystyle100-\text{V}}{\displaystyle10\cdot1000}=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-0}{\displaystyle40\cdot1000}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}-3\cdot\text{V}}{\displaystyle22\cdot1000}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{V}=\frac{\displaystyle880}{\displaystyle3}\approx293.33\space\text{V}\tag5$$
And, so we also get:
$$\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle880}{\displaystyle3}-0}{\displaystyle40\cdot1000}+\text{I}_8=\frac{\displaystyle100-\frac{\displaystyle880}{\displaystyle3}}{\displaystyle10\cdot1000}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{I}_8=-\frac{2}{75}\approx-0.02667\space\text{A}\tag6$$
And:
$$\text{I}_1=\frac{\displaystyle100-\frac{\displaystyle880}{\displaystyle3}}{\displaystyle10\cdot1000}=-
\frac{\displaystyle29}{\displaystyle1500}\approx-0.0193\space\text{A}\tag7$$
$$\text{I}_2=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle880}{\displaystyle3}-0}{\displaystyle40\cdot1000}=\frac{\displaystyle11}{\displaystyle1500}\approx0.0073\space\text{A}\tag8$$
$$\text{I}_3=\frac{\displaystyle\frac{\displaystyle880}{\displaystyle3}-3\cdot\frac{\displaystyle880}{\displaystyle3}}{\displaystyle22\cdot1000}=-\frac{\displaystyle2}{\displaystyle75}\approx-0.0267\space\text{A}\tag9$$
$$\text{I}_4=\frac{\displaystyle3\cdot\frac{\displaystyle880}{\displaystyle3}-0}{\displaystyle30\cdot1000}=\frac{\displaystyle11}{\displaystyle375}\approx0.0293\space\text{A}\tag{10}$$

Calculation of the power dissipated by R5. The maximum dissipated power can be determined if it depends on some variable quantity, but it is not indicated. I used graph theory applied to electrical networks:







The question doesn't make sense, if you're supposed to find a value for R that  consumes the most power. The 3Vo dependent voltage source is still a voltage source, with 0 resistance, which means it delivers more and more power as R gets smaller, without limit.
You can find the value of Vo easily. The current into Vo+ through the 10k resistor is (100-Vo+)/10000. The current into Vo+ through the 22k resistor is 2Vo+/22000. The current out of Vo+ is Vo+/40000. That still doesn't answer your question if you stated it correctly.

In my previous answer I used a 25V power supply, so there is a different response from that of the other interventions.
In the following I used a 100V power supply:












